# Is there someway to make "My Maps" in Google Maps available offline with location markers?

Tags: google-maps, offline, offline-map

I see how to save a map area offline on the Google Maps app, but how can I make sure the markers layer on "My Maps" is saved for offline use?

I see how to view it as a layer, but are all the layers saved for offline use?  (Seems unlikely and a waste of resources.) How do you save a select few for offline map use?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are talking about your "Starred locations" when you're talking about the markers layer on "My Maps"? These are stored in Google Bookmarks and [can be exported](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-starred-locations-from-google-maps/60289#60289) -- including the locations.

As a general note: The way Googe has set up its Maps/Geo operations leads to a likely reality that Google will "never" provide good offline capabilities. Your proper solution comes from something that does. And that something is increasingly likely using OpenStreetMap. My personal recommendations for apps that can also (easily enough) handle your exported starred Google Maps locations are OsmAnd and Maverick. [See OSM Wiki for details](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) and more options.

Answer (score 1):

I tried saving map data from Google Maps onto my phone, not even trying to save marker layers, and found it unreliable at best. I eventually decided to invest in a satnav app that had maps stored locally on the phone, along with favorites.

I have tried [CoPilot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alk.copilot.mapviewer) (expensive and crashy but has the features of a true satnav, ) and [Scout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telenav.app.android.scout_us) (much cheaper more reliable, better voice navigation but fewer features; no way-points and limited avoid area/route support).

Answer (score 0):

## Save locations for offline use

1. Search for a location.
2. Select the white info log at the bottom and scroll down. You'll see "Save map to use offline" at the bottom.
3. Google Maps will prompt you with the option "Save this map?" Go ahead and save it.
4. You'll see the "Map saved" confirmation.
5. Name the offline map.
6. To see the offline map, go to your profile.

**The maximum size for the area you can download is 50km x 50km. If you try to save an area bigger than that, you'll be asked to zoom in on a smaller area.**

If you're already on a map that you want to save, you can save it without searching for a place.

1. Move the map to the area you want to save.
2. Touch inside the search box at the top, and scroll down to the bottom of the page.
3. Touch Save map to use offline.

**You'll delete your saved offline maps if you clear your application data on your device.** But you won't delete your saved offline maps if you sign out of the Google Maps app, delete your Search History, or delete your Maps history.

To make sure that your map has the most up-to-date information, your **saved maps need to be updated at least once every 30 days. If you don’t update them, they’ll expire and be removed from your saved maps list.**

Since you cannot search an offline map, save several smaller maps covering the same area. Name the map after the area.

---

References:

- [Mashable - Your Guide to Saving Google Maps Locations for Offline Use](https://mashable.com/2014/06/17/google-maps-offline-tutorial/)
- [Google Maps Help - Download areas & navigate offline](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567)