# Offline Google Maps with favorite places and POIs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, offline, offline-map

I use Google Maps on my PC and have some favorite places added there. On my phone, I want to use an offline map. On my old phone, I used [RMaps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RMaps) with whole city maps downloaded with [Mobile Atlas Creator](https://mobac.sourceforge.io/) and manually added favorites and POIs on it. Now I bought a new phone and found out that RMaps is no longer available.

I'd like to add favorites/POIs to Google Maps and make sure they will be available with a whole city map when the phone is offline. But I don't want to be somewhere and open Android Google Maps and find out some tile for that area wasn't downloaded.

The best solution I see is to download the whole map from Google Maps or OSM and store the map on the phone and use some app that's able to open this offline map file and at the same time sync favorites/POIs with Google Maps.

I tried OsmAnd, but when I create a POI on it, it fails due to some authentication error. It's not trying to connect to Google, because other apps are able to sync with Google Apps. But there's no setting to add login data or create a new account.

Could somebody suggest a way to properly handle offline maps and sync favorites with Google Maps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there someway to make "My Maps" in Google Maps available offline with location markers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/is-there-someway-to-make-my-maps-in-google-maps-available-offline-with-locatio)

Answer (score 0):

You can add offline maps to Google Maps by setting the view to the region to want to store, then searching the phrase "OK maps". For custom maps, you currently need the Google Maps Engine app, AFAIK. Not sure if it had offline storage at present.

Comment: I have tried this "OK maps" trick, it doesn't work. When I zoom on an area I never soomed before its zoomed tiles aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no way to synch Google Maps favorites.

I discovered OsmAnd stores its favorites in `/osmand/favourites.gpx`. It's an XML file, each favorite has a name, category, latitude and longitude. In Google Maps, anywhere we can right-click and select "What's here?", it will show top-left the coordinates of the place right-clicked.

The solution I found was to manually handle my favorites. In OsmAnd, we go to Favorites and click on the middle-bottom button to import any new record in that file. When I need to add any new favorites, I'll just edit the file and import it again. This way, I'll always have control of them and can backup the file.