# Save "My maps" offline, including attribute information in Google Maps App

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

There are 2 functions in Google Maps that are quite suitable for a task of mine, but they would need to be **combined**, and after searching the internet and this site, I'm **not sure if it is possible or not**. I would appreciate confirmation about this question: If/how this is possible.

**1:** In Google Maps, one can create their **own maps** (see image below). These can then be displayed in the Google Maps app and can also be shared with others.

**2:** One can select **areas** of the map to be **saved offline** in the Google Maps App.

[image].

**Hence the question: is it possible to also save offline maps of my own maps/saved places?**

I have noticed that I can load the Map, if I then deconect the internet, it will still display all markers in the are. However, if I close (not minimize) the app and re-open it, they are gone. Likewise, if I click on one of the points I can't see the information saved for these points.

This makes me believer that offline-map functionality is not available for saved/own maps, even if I have downloaded an offline-version for the overlaping area. Is this correct? And if not, where can I find more information about how to achieve this.

I have found similar questions here and I do not mean to open up a duplicate question, I simply don't know if nothing has changed in the last 10 years.

2012: [Is there someway to make "My maps" in google maps available offline with location markers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/is-there-someway-to-make-my-maps-in-google-maps-available-offline-with-locatio)

2014: [Offline Google Maps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67840/offline-google-maps)

Comment: Hello, I notice you haven't responded or seen my answer yet, if it helps can you mark it as the accepted answer, if it doesn't can you be more specific or elaborate please?

Comment: Hi @Ethanmiller I can't see you answer any more..did you remove it? 
I saw one answer inbetween, however, it did not answer my question. Don't know, if that was your answer?